# Why doesn't stoi allow std::basic_string as an input?

Tags: c++, stdstring, stoi

To increase the performance I'm trying to substitute `std::string` with custom specializations of `std::basic_string` where I'm replacing standard allocator with custom ones. One thing surprised me: the `std::stoi` class of functions requires constant references to `std::string` (or `std::wstring`) as an input, so these functions don't work with other specializations. But logically these functions shouldn't care of how the memory is allocated; so their signatures look overly limiting.

While I could use the `std::from_chars` to read integers from any string-like data, I still wonder whether there was a reason why `std::stoi` is designed that way, and whether there are other STL functions designed to work with `std::basic_string` templates.

Comment: I am surprised that the are not defined for `std::string_view` in the first place.

Comment: Looks like it might be a standard defect since it makes sense to support `std::pmr::string` too. But for C++17, `stoi` should be completely replaced by `from_chars`, so I don't see a reason why it really needs to be fixed.

Comment: @alfC `std::string_view` is not guaranteed to be null-terminated, but the C function being called internally requires a null-terminated string.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I see, I didn't know these functions were calling corresponding c-functions. It is strange anyway because, std::string can have a null character in the middle. I guess is fine because a null character is never part of an integer.

Comment: For the OP, it doesn't seem to be that there is a good solution: either call the underlying c-function or `reinterpret_cast` from your custom `basic_string` to `std::string const&`.

Answer (score -2):

Because it's just a proxy function to C `std::strtol()`, converts its errors to C++ exceptions after a call to [[1]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) [[2]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/string.conversions#1)

```
std::strtol(str.c_str(), &ptr, base)
```

that takes only `char*`, null-terminated char array, hence other `char_type` specializations of `std::basic_string` are not accepted.

You can overload `strtol` for `std::basic_string` with your custom allocator, but you have to call it w/o `std::` namespace qualification:

```
using std::stoi;

int stoi(const mystring& str, std::size_t* pos = nullptr, int base = 10) {
  char *ptr;
  const long ret = std::strtol(str.c_str(), &ptr, base);

  // Required checks and throwing exceptions here

  if (pos)
    pos = ptr - str.c_str();
  return static_cast<int>(ret);
}
```

As for `std::string_view`, it is not required to refer a null-terminated string, thus it does not have `std::string_view::c_str()` and its `data()` is not suitable for `std::strtol()`.

Comment: All `basic_string` specializations are null terminated. `strtol()` would work just fine with them. There is no technical reason that `stoi()` couldn't accept specializations other than the standard committee simply hasn't defined the standard that way.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I can't find any mention of `basic_string::c_str()` in my answer. All specializations are for `char*` and `wchar_t*`, they cover all available C functions, it does not need to be a template and accept other specializations.

Comment: The whole point is that `.c_str()` will work in the exact same way for other specializations of `basic_string`.

Comment: @L.F. What other specializations? There are no C functions for other types except `char*` and `wchar_t*`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Alloc>` for allocators `Alloc` other than `std::allocator<char>`.  Of course the `char_type` must be `char` (or `wchar_t`).

Comment: @273K your answer claims that because `strtol()` requires a null terminated `char*` string, `stoi()` couldn't possibly accept other specializations of `basic_string`, and that is simply not true. And in this case, the specialization being asked about is on the Allocator, not the character type. Since `stoi()` requires `std::(w)string` specifically, `basic_string` specializations that use `char`/`wchar_t` with custom allocators can't be used with `stoi()` even though `strtol()` would be just fine with it

Comment: @RemyLebeau When I talked about a null terminated string, I talked about `string_view`. Please don't tell about what I have not said.

Comment: @273K The 1st half of your answer clearly does not talk about `string_view`. The 2nd half of your answer is technically correct, but doesn't apply to the question asked by the OP. So basically, your entire answer is wrong and needs to be fixed or deleted.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The first half is about `char*`, not about `.c_str()`. I mentions only specializations for `char_type`. L.F. is rights that I missed specializations for allocators.

Comment: @273K The 1st half of your answer refers to `stoi()` and how it calls `strtol()`. That would work just fine with all specializations of `basic_string` that use `char`/`wchar_t` for their character type. All specializations of `basic_string` have `c_str()`

Comment: @273K I'm not here to be kind. This is a Q&A site. I'm here to answer questions, and to make sure other answers are accurate and applicable to the questions being asked. Your answer does not adequately or correctly address the OP's actual question.

Comment: I didn't ask anything about `std::string_view`.